# Uninstalled Pil/Pillow but can still import from it?

Tags: python-imaging-library

I've run the following commands on the virtual enviroment.

```
pip uninstall pillow
Skipping pillow as it is not installed.

pip uninstall pil
Skipping pil as it is not installed.
```

However when I do this in the console:

import PIL print PIL.PILLOW_VERSION

I get this: 5.3.0

import PIL print PIL.VERSION

I get this: 1.1.7

When I try to reinstall PIL in case there was an issue when installing it, I get this:
*Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pil (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pil*

When I try to uninstall from the python interpreter directly:
*Cannot uninstall 'PIL'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.*

I'm trying to completely remove PIL and PILLOW on a windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going into the Python interpreter and writing

```
>>> import PIL
>>> PIL
```

You should then see a path to the Pillow module, which you can manually remove.